# How to solve this coding decoding puzzle?

Tags: cipher

If in a certain code language CMWAX is coded as 51525525. Then what is the code for CIPKZ?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: should it be 51525326 instead??

Comment: I  also thought that. But it was not given. Do you think it in the way that the number of position + 2?

Comment: Where did you find this puzzle? Could  you please provide the source of it, so that we can ensure that it's not from an ongoing puzzle competition @mathmaniac.

Comment: It was came in IBPS PO exam in India last year.

Comment: @mathmaniac Welcome to Puzzling! It looks like you’ve tried asking a few questions from an exam. Note that for content you did not create yourself, **[proper attribution](/help/referencing)** is required here. Please [edit] your posts themselves to include (at minimum) where this came from, and the URL of the test or question if it can be found online.  Posts which use someone else's content without attribution are generally deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess it would be

> $510201530$

Reasoning

> Convert the string to numbers corresponding to the letter positions in the alphabet $CMWAX \rightarrow 3,13,23,1,24$
>  Take the next multiples of $5$ after each of these numbers
>  $3,13,23,1,24 \rightarrow 5,15,25,5,25$
>  Concatenate the result
>  $5,15,25,5,25 \rightarrow 51525525$
>  For the example in question, we have
>  $CIPKZ \rightarrow 3,9,16,11,26 \rightarrow 5,10,20,15,30 \rightarrow 510201530$